# How to toggle two components in React using onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I have a calendar with one month only that I've created using </table/> tag, The concept that I'm working on is when I click on a random day I want to create an event(**form**) and submit it, but if there is already an event inside this day I want to show the overview( of the event that has been created in this day(something like google calendar).

How I can toggle onClick between Form( to create an event on this day) and Event components based on the event created?

**Calendar Component**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Day from './Day';
import Event from './Event';


const Calendar = () => {
    const [eventForm, showEventFrom] = useState(false);
    const [eventName, setEventName] = useState("");
    const [eventList, setEventList] = useState([]);
    console.log(eventList);
    
    //Submit function
    const submitHandle = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      if(!eventName) {
          alert("Please Enter a name for Your Event")
      }
      else {
        const newEvent = {id : new Date().getTime().toString(), title: eventName}
        setEventList(newEvent);
        setEventName("");
      }
    };

    //Show Event Function
    const handleEvent = () => {
      showEventFrom(!eventForm)
    }

    console.log();
    
    return (
        <>
      <table className="table-calendar" >
        <tr>
        <th colspan="7">January</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <th>S</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>S</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <Day day="1" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="2" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="3" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="4" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="5" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="6" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="7" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <Day day="8" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="9" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="10" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="11" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="12" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="13" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="14" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        </tr>
      </table>

      {eventForm ? (<form className="event-form" onSubmit={submitHandle}>
          <h3>Create an event</h3>
          <input type="text" 
                 placeholder="Event Name" 
                 className="event-name" 
                 value={eventName}
                 onChange={(e)=> setEventName(e.target.value)}/>

           <div className="btn-container">
            <button type="submit"
                    className="btn">Submit</button>
            <button className="btn">Delete</button>
           </div>
      </form>) : ""}
      
      <Event listEvent={eventList}/>
    </>
    )
}

export default Calendar;
```

**Event Component**

```
import React from 'react'

const Event = ({listEvent}) => {
    const {id, title} = listEvent;
    return (
       <div className="event-pop-up" key={id}>
           <h1>Event : {title}</h1>
       </div>
    )
}

export default Event
```

What do you think? Any suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should store the date along with the event name in the events list array.

Next time check if there are any events created on the selected dat, then display only form if no events and both form and list if events are already there.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate your explanations with some code Kishanlal  :D I would appreciate it